# javascript join array to another

Tags: javascript

I want to write a function to join an array to another but different way :

```
var myNumbers = [10,20,3,4,2]
var myOperations = ['+','-','*','/']
```

I want the operators locate between myNumbers element :
10+20-3*4/2 = 54

thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow ! Please read the [tour], [help] and [ask]. Users are expected to show their attempts or research in their question, to ensure a better reception.

Comment: Also, `10+20-3*4/2` is 24

Answer (score 0):

Just Change the var str = 0 to str = ''

```js
var myNumbers = [10,20,3,4,2]
var myOperations = ['+','-','*','/'];
var str = '';
for(var i = 0 ; i < myNumbers.length ; i++){
  if(myOperations[i]){
    str += myNumbers[i] + myOperations[i]; 
  }else{
    str += myNumbers[i];
  }
}
console.log(str);
```

Comment: `010+20-3*4/2`?

Comment: that `010` , the `0` before `10` is will not considered in calculatoin . @CodeRed

Comment: Point taken. But can syntactically be avoided.

Comment: Yess i can be . @CodeRed

Comment: @PushprajsinhChudasama Depends a bit on how the calculation is done. `eval('010')` will return `8`.

Comment: @Ivar, that is why I am telling PushprajsinhChudasama that it could be avoided

Comment: @CodeRed Yes, sorry, annotated the wrong person.

Comment: @Ivar all is well brother

Answer (score 0):

Some duplicates questions have already been pointed by other members and they could have helped you. Please find below a solution that I worked out for your problem.

```
var numbersAndOperations = myNumbers.map((a, i) => myOperations[i] ? [a, myOperations[i]] : [a])
/* this makes a 2 levels deep array from your 2 and avoids any undefined values through a ternary operator.
If you don't know ternary operators they are a shorthand for an if condition.
[[10, "+"], [20, "-"], [3, "*"], [4, "/"], [2]] */

const myMathString = numbersAndOperations.flat(2).join(',').replace(/,/g, '')
// this turns it into a string and remove the comas: "10+20-3*4/2"

function mathEval(mathString) { // this hack evaluates your math function and immediately returns a result.
  return new Function('return ' + mathString)();
}

console.log(mathEval(myMathString)); // 24. The result is actually 24 because * and / are evaluated before the + and -
```

Hope that it helps :)